# How can I extract the number within the parenthesis in this span tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, numbers

I'm trying to take the value in the tag below. More specifically I want the number from in between the parenthesis.

```
<span class="bv-rating-label bv-text-link">   (12)  </span>
```

the line in my script that is not returning the correct response:

```
'reviews' : item.find('span', {'class': 'bv-rating-label bv-text-link'}).text
```

I have also tried

```
'reviews' : int(item.find('span', {'class': 'bv-rating-label bv-text-link'}).text)
```

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter for only digits and remove the parenthesis, you can use the `.isdigit()` method.

```
result = ''.join(
    tag for tag in soup.find('span', class_='bv-rating-label bv-text link').text
    if tag.isdigit()
    )
>>> print(result)
12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4
import re

'reviews' : item.find('span', {'class': 'bv-rating-label bv-text-link'}).text

for item in items:
    print(re.sub(r" ?\([^)]+\)", "", item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex to the rescue.

```
import re
string_='<span class="bv-rating-label bv-text-link">   (12)  </span>'
num = int(re.search(r'>\s*\((\d+)\)\s*</span>', string_)[1])
```

The `num` contains the required number in int format